# Creating ellipse marker with line pattern fill in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style, markers, fill

How can I create an ellipse marker with line pattern fill in QGIS?

Like this:
[image]

I have already made simpler symbols, but there is no solution with the ellipse

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the different symbols for each half of the ellipse:

- make a Geometry Generator symbol layer
- use this expression

```sql
with_variable('ellipse',
    make_ellipse( $geometry, 10, 5, 0),    -- make an ellipse and assign it to a variable
        rotate(
            intersection(                  -- get intersection of rectangle and ellipse to 'clip' half of it
                 make_rectangle_3points(   -- make a rectangle that is half the bounding box of the ellipse
                        project($geometry,  y_max(@ellipse) - y($geometry), 0),  -- project a point from the original point directly north by half the height of the ellipse
                        project($geometry,  y_max(@ellipse) - y($geometry), radians(180)),  -- project a point from the original point directly south by half the height of the ellipse
                        make_point(x_max(@ellipse), y_min(@ellipse))  -- make a point of the 'lower right' corner of the bounds of the ellipse
                 ),
                 @ellipse      -- @ellipse is the variable name of the ellipse made above
            ),      
        120, $geometry     -- rotate the half-ellipse, 120 is the rotation angle, $geometry is the center of rotation (the original point geometry)
        )
)
```

- duplicate the symbol layer
- change angle in `rotate` by 180 degrees so the new symbol layer aligns with the first (in my case `120`->`300`)
- style the 2 symbol layers as desired
- don't forget to set `Units` to `Millimeter` for a scalable symbol

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use Geometry Generator with the following expression:

```
make_ellipse(centroid($geometry), 1, 2, 0)
```

Change values 1 (semi_major_axis) and 2 (semi_minor_axis).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Filled Marker`.

- Choose the semi-circle shape
- set your desired rotation and give it a line fill.
- Then add another symbol layer with the semi-circle `Filled Marker` (or duplicate first symbol layer)
- give it the opposite rotation so they align, make this a simple fill (with No Brush).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice
! But I need an ellipse 
not a circle.