# Creation of an ellipse in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to express the required distances between wind turbine. Therefore I use an ellipse for each turbine. The turbine can be a point or the ellipse can be created without the point.

What I need to know is: I have the height of the turbine in meters. Let's say 150 m. I want the ellipse to be x-times 150 m long and y-times 150 m wide. How do I do this?

Comment: Shapetools plugin has 'Ellipsis+Roses.' https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-shapetools-plugin#create-shapes for documentation.

Comment: How is your turbine data structured, and what have you tried so far? For example, there is a "make_ellipse" function in the expression editor which would likely do what you need.

Comment: Please, read these articles: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/423364/creating-ellipse-marker-with-line-pattern-fill-in-qgis, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394753/calculating-semi-major-and-semi-minor-axis-length-of-an-ellipse-in-qgis, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283205/creating-ellipse-in-qgis, and then come again with more specific issues after you have you tried something. Please, do not see it in a rude way :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an expression.

I have width and height columns which I use as input to the expression:

```
make_ellipse( center:=$geometry, semi_major_axis:="height", semi_minor_axis:="width", azimuth:=0)
```

You can set fixed distances if you want to.

I use it to create a styling:
[image]

If you need the geometries as a layer use [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisgeometrybyexpression).